# Odoo13 Windows Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404

Tags: windows, http-status-code-404, odoo, odoo-13

My website was working fine on windows, suddenly i start facing the below issues

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (NOT FOUND)
web.assets_frontend.css:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (NOT FOUND)
web.assets_common_minimal_js.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (NOT FOUND)
web.assets_frontend_minimal_js.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (NOT FOUND)
about:blank:1 The resource https://widget-v4.tidiochat.com/1_68_0/static/js/chunk-WidgetIframe-af06857f6bb1cfd0c730.js was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load event. Please make sure it has an appropriate `as` value and it is preloaded intentionally.
web.assets_common.css:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (NOT FOUND)
web.assets_frontend.css:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (NOT FOUND)

this case only when I view the website from another pc but from the same server its working fine on localhost:8069

I disable the firewall to be sure the firewall is not blocking anything.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try clearing the cookies?

Comment: yes i did but its not working you can view my issue with the link

http://www.arcom.com.sa:8069/

Comment: Please check if there is any typo in the '.js' and '.css' url.